# html5-video big centered play button in chrome like firefox

Tags: html5-video

Is there a solution to display a big play button in the center of the video in chrome browser like in mozilla firefox?

```
 <video src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/a/a4/BBH_gravitational_lensing_of_gw150914.webm/BBH_gravitational_lensing_of_gw150914.webm.480p.webm" width="100%" controls></video>
```

Chrome:
[Chrome video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBpQg.jpg)

Firefox:
[Firefox video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQRW2.jpg)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30309584/overlay-play-button-over-video

Comment: oh. and ... compatible with firefox!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534078/html5-video-play-button-not-working-in-firefox